# Is there any missing below codes?

Tags: python, django

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from .models import Destination
# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    dest1 = Destination.objects.all()
    return render(request,"index.html",{'dest1':dest1})
```

> **Error: from .models import Destination ImportError: cannot import name 'Destination' from 'travellor.models' (C:\Users\Raja
>   Kumar\projects\telusko\travellor\models.py)**

can anyone help me out ?

Comment: Please, copy and paste models and views code from travellor app.

Answer (score 0):

The error happens in `from .models import Destination`. It's basically saying that there is no such model in models.py module.

Comment: from django.shortcuts import render

from travellor.models import Destination
# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    dest1 = Destination()
    dest1.name ='Mumbai'
    return render(request,"index.html",{'dest1':dest1})

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to import a model from current app but this model doesn't exists.

for external imports, you need to point the app before models

```
from destination.models import Destination
```

Change `destination` to the name of your app if it is different

Comment: after point out the app name before models Import Error occured from django.shortcuts import render

from travellor.models import Destination
# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    dest1 = Destination()
    dest1.name ='Mumbai'
    return render(request,"index.html",{'dest1':dest1})